# how to add text multi lingual in asp.net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to asp.net. I am making a website in which the text is multilingual. When i Add text of different language(other than English) in text box and submit it. then its shows unformatted patterns of text. so tell me how can i add multi-lingual text to website(other than English).

Thanks in advance

Comment: also see possible duplicates of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751173/how-to-make-multilingual-site-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

this is concept of globalization in Asp.net.
Check out these samples

- [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7998/Creating-multilingual-websites-Part-1)
- [Asp.net Blog](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-multi-lingual-site-with-localization)